# How to fix https-proxy-agent Machine-In-The-Middle vulnerability?

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-scripts

I have a hobby project where I am learning react. A few days ago I updated mypackages and got the following:

> found 21 high severity vulnerabilities in 917686 scanned packages   21
>   vulnerabilities require manual review. See the full report for
>   details.

npm audit:

> Package         https-proxy-agent
>
> Patched in      >=2.2.3
>
> Dependency of   npm
>
> Path            npm > libnpm > npm-registry-fetch >
>   make-fetch-happen >
>
> More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1184
>
> High            Machine-In-The-Middle
>
> Package         https-proxy-agent
>
> Patched in      >=2.2.3

I go to the adviosory link above and it tells me:

> Upgrade to version 3.0.0 or 2.2.3.

I uninstalled current versions and installed first the 3.0.0 version but nothing changed. Uninstalled again and installed 2.2.3 version of the https-proxy-agent 
and still nothing changed.

I did do "npm audit fix" after each version.

I googled and tried adding

```
  "resolutions": {      
    "https-proxy-agent": "^3.0.0"       
  },
```

and did 3 npm steps but that did not help.

I have been at this for days and im not getting anywhere. what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time i figured this out...

Apperently I had  "npm": "^6.12.0" in my package.json and when I removed it the errors vent away.